# input value of a to check whether a is 0 or not

Tags: c++

I wrote a code in which we have to input value for `a` and  then if the value for a is zero, it prints out that `a` is zero. But the code is not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const char a = a;

int main()
{
    cout << " Enter the value of a";
    cin >> a;
    if (a != 0)
    {
        cout << "a is not 0";
    }
}
```

Comment: What should initialization of a variable with itself do (`const char a = a;`)?

Comment: I just wanted to declare that a is a variable which we will input .

Comment: Why not simply `char a;`? Adding `const` will prevent to update this variable by reading from the input stream. Initialization by (previously uninitialized) `a` generally causes undefined behavior (IIRC there is some exception for chars).

Comment: @DanielLangr It teaches a fundamental principle of Objectivism. A is A.

Comment: @user4581301 :) However, in C++, `=` does not represent the "is" relation.

Comment: True, @DanielLangr , but I can't pass up an opening like that.

Comment: @NityodayTekchandani If you don't know how to declare a variable, you should definitely read at least some introductory book/material about C++.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes I have this book and I am trying to understand from that , and experimenting things my self , it is more like a theory one

Comment: Why did I get -1 for this question ?

Comment: @DanielLangr yes, char a; works, at first I tried const char a; and it did not work hence I tried the a=a; thing . Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `const` to be able to change the value. And because `a` is `char`, you need to add quotes to the comparison.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

char a;

int main()
{
    cout << " Enter the value of a";
    cin >> a;
    if (a != '0')
    {
        cout << "a is not 0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood.  I was first using const char a; but it did not work so I tried the a=a; thing, now the char a; work and yes the quotes. The code works now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a c++ pro.
But it looks like you are trying to alter a const value. However, const values are unchangeable.
Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I used the char a; and now the code works , also added quotes besides 0 . Thank you!